# Symfony 3 Security: How to disable in_memory provider in production

Tags: symfony, security, config

I have a Symfony 3.4 app which uses an LDAP authentication provider. I recently added an 'in_memory' provider (chained) so I can easily test the app while offline (i.e. while not connected to ldap server).

I understand that I cannot override Symfony security config. So how can I disable the 'in_memory' provider in the production environment but allow both 'in_memory' and 'ldap' in the dev environment?

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Security\User\LdapUser: plaintext
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, ldap_user]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: 'user',  roles: 'ROLE_USER'  }
                    admin: { password: 'admin', roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
        ldap_user:
            id: app.ext_ldap_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false
            anonymous: ~

        main:
            http_basic:
                provider: in_memory
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: ldap_user
            form_login_ldap:
                service: app.ldap
                dn_string: '%ldap_dn_string%'
                query_string: '%ldap_query_string%'
                remember_me: true
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                success_handler: AppBundle\Security\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: /
            logout_on_user_change: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

Comment: Can you show your security.yml file?

Answer (score 2):

Use two firewalls [restricted by host](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html#restricting-by-host), one that matches your local host and uses the chained providers, the other matching your prod host and using only the LDAP provider.

That would look something like:

```
#config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, ldap_provider]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    foo: { password: test }
        ldap_provider:
            #...

    firewalls:
        firewall_dev:
            host: ^admin\.localhost$
            provider: chain_provider
            #...
        firewall_prod:
            host: ^admin\.example\.com$
            provider: ldap_provider
            #...
```